# Rails generate has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there a way to generate has_many association for a column using `Rails generate scaffold` command in the console?

I know `belongs_to` is available and there are use cases of `references` but not sure of `has_many`

Answer (score 91, accepted):

There is no column for a `has_many` relationship. A `belongs_to` is backed by a column which holds a foreign key.

So if you generate a scaffold: `rails g scaffold Post`

And then you generate another scaffold: `rails g scaffold Comment post:references`

Then rails will create a migration that adds a column named `post_id` to the Comment table and creates an index on it. For both tables, it creates foreign key constraints between `comments(post_id)` and `posts(id)`. Rails will also add `belongs_to :post` in the Comment model.

At anytime you can add a `has_many` to a model as long as another model `belongs_to` the first model and has a migration with the foreign key column.

Comment: I wonder, can a model that is the "one-side" in a one-many relation not be defined in a single "rails generate model" command (?)