# Define rails assosiations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a database architecture. I also have read [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)
So I will have following models:

**Author**

```
name, has_many:questions, has_many:comments, has_many:edits
```

**Question**

```
title, body , author_id, has_many:comments, belongs_to:author
```

**Comment**

```
body, question_id, author_id, belongs_to:question, has_many:edits, belongs_to:author
```

**Edit**

```
body, comment_id, author_id, belongs_to:comment, belongs_to:author
```

As you can see, question can have many comments and each comment can have many edits. And author can have many questions, edits and comments

**Main question is: did I use `has_many` and `belongs_to` assosiations correctly?!**

*Additional info:*
I don't know if it is relevant, but I want to use following scaffold migrations:

```
rails generate scaffold Question title:string body:text author_id:integer has_many:comments belongs_to:author

rails generate scaffold Comment body:text question_id:integer author_id:integer belongs_to:question has_many:edits belongs_to:author

rails generate scaffold Edit body:text comment_id:integer author_id:integer belongs_to:comment belongs_to:author

rails generate scaffold Author name:string has_many:questions has_many:comments has_many:edits
```

UPD: My scaffolds are incorrect. I should use something like this:

rails generate scaffold Question title:string body:text user:references
rails generate scaffold Comment body:text user:references question:references
rails generate scaffold Edit body:text user:references question:references

[As suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20369254/2950593)

Comment: Why did someone downvoted this?!

Comment: could you format your models and their associations as code? it's easier to follow the logic of your associations if we see the actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both your associations and scaffolds are correct. I would just advice to use **dependent: :destroy** after all your belongs_to associations so when for example an author is deleted all his questions are deleted from you database aswell.

*For example:*

```
Class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :author, dependent: :destroy
end
```

That way you can avoid a big mess in your database.